# File I/O program in C: Segmention Fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, file, io, embedded, spi

I was writing a program to read hexcodes from a file and feed it to another chip via SPI. I am trying to read each line from the hexfile using **fgets** and then parse it using **sscanf** into a **unsinged int array** The format of the hexfile is as follows:

```
ff32
34dc
1234
32d4
```

....

```
int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp1;
    int i = 0;
    fp1 = fopen("hexfile.txt", "r+");
    char line[500];
    unsigned int hex[40];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp1) != NULL) {

        while (sscanf(line, "%x", &hex[i]) == 1) {
                    printf("%4x \n", hex[i]);
                    i++;
            }
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

**Error:** Segmentation Fault (core dumped) Which I know roughly results when you try to dereference a NULL pointer. But what is wrong with my code? Second, is there a better way to read from a file using other File I/O functions without dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: fopen return code is not tested. Range test (<40) in not done inside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the while and replace it with if:

```
FILE *fp1;
int i = 0;
fp1 = fopen("d:\hexfile.txt", "r+");
char line[500];
unsigned int hex[40];

while (fgets(line, 8, fp1) != NULL) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%x", &hex[i]) == 1) {  /*here while => if */ 
        printf("%4x \n", hex[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

fclose(fp1);
```

Comment: Thanks this solved it, what is wrong with having while? Doesn't sscanf return 1 whenever it can read an input from the line?

Comment: well , you already read the line ,so you don't need the other while it simply keep reading the same "line" and return 1 ! , you just need to insure that it read that line once ! , easy mistake !

Comment: Note the difference between `sscanf(line,...` and `fscanf(fp1,...)`. In OP's `while` loop, the first will keep doing the same thing unless you replace `line`. In the second, more data is read from the file `fp1`.

Answer (score 0):

This loop will repeat for ever or until writing to `hex[i]` breaks something

```
while (sscanf(line, "%x", &hex[i]) == 1) {
```

In answer to OP's second question, here is another way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
    FILE *fp1;
    int i = 0, j;
    unsigned int hex[40];
    fp1 = fopen("hexfile.txt", "rt");
    while (i<40 && fscanf (fp1, "%x", &hex[i]) == 1)
        i++;
    fclose(fp1);

    for (j=0; j<i; j++)               // check
        printf("%4x \n", hex[j]);
    return 0;
}
```